# Why adding super() in Entity class?

Tags: java, entity

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

   private int eid;
   private String ename;

   public Employee(int eid, String ename) {
      super( );
      this.eid = eid;
      this.ename = ename;
   }
 }
```

What is the need of calling super() in this entity class constructor? Actually super() is used to call immediate parent constructor. Here we didnt extend any classes. Then what is the need for calling super() in constructor?

Comment: There's no need.

Comment: Sounds like a non-question. I'd ask the author what they think it does.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need. If you omit it, the compiler will automatically insert a call to the default no-argument constructor of the superclass (`Object` in this case).

Note that this would also be true if your entity actually did extend a specific class. The only reason to ever use `super(...)` is to call a non-default superclass constructor (i.e. a constructor that requires arguments).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need as your have already identified that super is used to call the immediate parent class and since there is no immediate parent class, so there is no need.

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) says:

> **Note**: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.

Comment: Sure there's an immediate parent class. It's `Object`. And the reason that there's no need to call `super()` is because the compiler inlines the call automatically if it's not present.